# Using modules in Ceylon

Tags: module, ceylon

I'm checking out Ceylon. I want to play with the HTML module, but have no idea how to import it. IMHO the [documentation about modules](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/modules/) do not address this simple task.

Thank you
Gilad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add it to your module descriptor, as described in [this section](http://ceylon-lang.org/documentation/1.2/tour/modules/#dependencies_and_module_descriptors).

```
module your.module "1.0.0" {
    import ceylon.html "1.2.2";
}
```

If you’re on the [web IDE](http://try.ceylon-lang.org/), you’ll need to check the “Advanced” checkbox (to the right of Run / Stop / Clean / Share) to see the `module.ceylon` file.

Answer (score 1):

To import the module itself, you'll need a `module.ceylon` file that looks like:

```
module com.example.mymodule "1.0.0" {
    shared import ceylon.html "1.2.2";
}
```

You can omit `shared` if nothing from `ceylon.html` appears in the public api of your module.